# Inspect doesn't find azure storage network rules

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-storage, inspec

Trying to use inspec to check my storage accounts in azure have vnets attached, but inspec is just returning nulls.

Checked the docs here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account?view=azure-cli-latest) to get the property names right, and use the portal and `az storage list --name (storagename)` and all my end matches up - but inspec says no.

Anyone come across this before?

```
attached_networks = ['vnet-'+env,'vnet-'+env+'fw']

control 'Networking tests' do
    title 'Testing PAFW Storage Networking rules'
    impact 'high'

    describe azure_storage_account(resource_group: rg_name, name: diag_storage_name) do
          its('properties.networkAcls.virtualNetworkRules') { should be attached_networks }
    end
end






Networking tests: Testin Storage Networking rules
     ×  Azure Storage Account - api_version: 2023-01-01 latest: rg Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts mystorage properties.networkAcls.virtualNetworkRules is expected to equal "vnet-test" and "vnet-test-fw"
     can't convert #<Class:0x0000558969393da0>::AzureResourceProbe to Array (#<Class:0x0000558969393da0>::AzureResourceProbe#to_ary gives #<Class:0x0000558969393da0>::NullResponse)
```